# EF Core 6 different change tracking behavior for entities under same object

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-6.0

**Context**: `Context` has `NoTracking` behaviour set in `Configuration` method for Context for all commands/queries. `TruckModel` and `TruckType` are navigation properties of `TruckDescription`. `TruckDescription` also has `TruckRoot` navigation property. `TruckRoot` has multiple `TruckDescription` properties (snapshot values). All entities have `Id` identity column as primary key. `TruckDescription` also has an additional composite key of some two other tables. Saving `TruckDescription` is done by `Context.Attach`-ing object created as:

```
{
    TruckRoot = truckRoot;
    TruckModel = new TruckModelDetail(
        new TruckManufacturerDetail
        {
            Id = truck.TruckModel.TruckManufacturer.Id
        })
    {
        Id = truck.TruckModel.Id
    };
    TruckType = new TruckTypeDetail
    {
        Id = truck.TruckType.Id,
    };
}
```

where `truckRoot` is created as :

```
await Context.Set<TruckRoot>()
             .Include(r => r.Description)
                 .ThenInclude(d => d.TruckModel)
             .Include(r => r.Description)
                 .ThenInclude(d => d.TruckType)
             .SingleOrDefaultAsync(r => r.PublicId == publicId);
```

Therefore when saving, `truckRoot` may contain `truckType` and `truckModel` with same Id as ones that are being saved. When that happens for `TruckModel` error is thrown, but when that happens for `truckType` code executes without an error and the test passes. I concluded that the change tracker is treating them differently and my question is why?

Error message is:

> The instance of entity type 'TruckModelDetail' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id: 1}' is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached

First I save one truck that is POCO object, than I create another truck (also POCO) based on the first one and try to save that too.

Code snippet from test:

```
await Executor.Dispatch(_truckRootSaveCommand);   <----
_truck = new Truck(_truck.PublicId,
    Context.Set<TruckDescription>().First().CreatedDate.Ticks,
    _truck.DotLastInspection,
    _truck.TruckManufacturer,
    _truck.TruckModel,
    _truck.TruckType,
    _truck.Dimension)
{
    WIN = "testWIN",
};

await Executor.Dispatch(new TruckSaveCommand(_truck));    <----
```

If I change `truckModel` to some new type in second truck object the test passes.

Example:

```
_truck = new Truck(_truck.PublicId,
    Context.Set<TruckDescription>().First().CreatedDate.Ticks,
    _truck.DotLastInspection,
    _truck.TruckManufacturer,
    new TruckModel(new TruckManufacturer { Id = Const.INDEX_START }) { Id = Const.INDEX_START + 1 },    <----
    //_truck.TruckModel,
    _truck.TruckType,
    _truck.Dimension)
{
    WIN = "testWIN",
};
```

When test fails, ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView is

```
TruckDescription {Id: -2147482646} Added
  Id: -2147482646 PK Temporary
  TruckModelId: 1 FK
  TruckRootId: 1 AK FK
  TruckTypeId: 1 FK
  TruckModel: {Id: 1}     <----
  TruckRoot: {Id: 1}
  TruckType: {Id: 1}
TruckDescription {Id: 1} Unchanged
  Id: 1 PK
  TruckModelId: 0 FK Unknown
  TruckRootId: 1 AK FK
  TruckTypeId: 0 FK Unknown
  TruckModel: {Id: 1}       <----
  TruckRoot: {Id: 1}
  TruckType: <not found>
```

And It creates Two `TruckModelDetail` objects:

```
TruckModelDetail {Id: 1} Unchanged
  Id: 1 PK
  Name: 'truckModelName'
  TruckManufacturerId: 0 FK Unknown
  TruckManufacturer: <null>
TruckModelDetail {Id: 1} Unchanged
  Id: 1 PK
  Name: 'truckModelName'
  TruckManufacturerId: 0 FK Unknown
  TruckManufacturer: <null>
```

When test passes, ChangeTracker.DebugView.LongView shows

```
TruckDescription {Id: -2147482646} Added
  Id: -2147482646 PK Temporary
  TruckModelId: 2 FK
  TruckRootId: 1 AK FK
  TruckTypeId: 1 FK
  WIN: 'testWIN'
  TruckModel: {Id: 2}
  TruckRoot: {Id: 1}
  TruckType: {Id: 1}  <----
TruckDescription {Id: 1} Unchanged
  Id: 1 PK
  TruckModelId: 1 FK
  TruckRootId: 1 AK FK
  TruckTypeId: 1 FK
  WIN: 'win'
  TruckModel: {Id: 1}
  TruckRoot: {Id: 1}
  TruckType: {Id: 1}  <----
```

And creates only one TruckType object:

```
TrailerTypeDetail {Id: 1} Unchanged
  Id: 1 PK
  Name: 'trailerType'
```

which indicates that there are two `TruckModel` objects in the changeTracker, while `TruckType` is present only once. I checked the code, and both `TruckModel` and `TruckType` are created in same way, same number of times. This are `Console.WriteLine` from constructors of these two objects:

```
TruckModelDetail Constructor CALLED! Constructor with 2 argument.
TruckTypeDetail Constructor CALLED! Constructor with 1 argument called.
TruckModelDetail Constructor CALLED! Constructor with 1 argument.
TruckTypeDetail Constructor CALLED! Constructor with 1 argument called.
TruckModelDetail Constructor CALLED! Constructor with 1 argument.
TruckTypeDetail Constructor CALLED! Constructor with 1 argument called.
TruckModelDetail Constructor CALLED! Constructor with 1 argument.
TruckTypeDetail Constructor CALLED! Constructor with 1 argument called.
```